# Parity of number of $0-1$ matrices with no zero rows

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k$ be a positive integer. What is the formula for the number of $0-1$ matrices of size  $k\times k$  such that no rows of the matrices are all $0$s (note columns can be all $0$s)? When is this number odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider one row, since all element are either $0$ or $1$, there are $2^k$ ways to write these elements. And you don't want them to be all $0$s,finally we have $2^k - 1$ ways to write this row.

We have in total $k$ rows, for each of which we have $2^k - 1$ ways to write it, so we have $(2^k - 1)^k$ ways to write the matrix.

$2^k -1 $ is odd, so is its power $(2^k - 1)^k$